# MapReduce code error: Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am new to MapReduce.

I ran a couple of already stored examples of MapReduce on Cloudera VM (4.4), they ran fine. I looked into some programs over the net and tried to do a small execution which threw errors. I tried looking through the logs but couldn't get anything. Hoping anyone could help me resolving the issue here, I'm pasting my code and log snapshots for your reference.

*The only thing I can think of from the logs is that I'm running the code on Hadoop-2, this program I found dated almost a year ago on the net, which probably is for Hadoop-1. May be some of the classes are deprecated that are causing the issue.*

**MapReduce Code** (*I'm trying to find the min & max temperatures from a file record*):

```
public class WeatherData {
    public class MaxTemperatureMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text, Text>{

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable arg0, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter arg2)
        throws IOException{

            String line = value.toString();

            String date = line.substring(7, 14);

            float temp_Max = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(39,45).trim());
            float temp_Min = Float.parseFloat(line.substring(47,53).trim());

            if(temp_Max > 40.0){
                output.collect((Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text("Hot Day" + date), 
                        (Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text(String.valueOf(temp_Max)));
            }

            if(temp_Min < 10){
                output.collect((Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text("Cold Day" + date), 
                        (Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text(String.valueOf(temp_Min)));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MaxTemperatureReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> Values, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException{

            String temperature = Values.next().toString();
            output.collect(key, (Text) new org.apache.hadoop.io.Text(temperature));
        }
    }
```

***JobTracker Log***:

```
2014-03-18 23:59:22,961 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing a failed task task_201403170135_0018_m_000001
2014-03-18 23:59:22,962 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2014-03-18 23:59:22,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (MAP) 'attempt_201403170135_0018_m_000001_2' to tip task_201403170135_0018_m_000001, for tracker 'tracker_localhost.localdomain:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:49298'
2014-03-18 23:59:22,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing data-local task task_201403170135_0018_m_000001
2014-03-18 23:59:22,963 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Removing task 'attempt_201403170135_0018_m_000001_1'
2014-03-18 23:59:23,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: TaskTracker at 'localhost.localdomain' turned 'flaky'
2014-03-18 23:59:23,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing a failed task task_201403170135_0018_m_000000
2014-03-18 23:59:23,268 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2014-03-18 23:59:23,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (MAP) 'attempt_201403170135_0018_m_000000_2' to tip task_201403170135_0018_m_000000, for tracker 'tracker_localhost.localdomain:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:49298'
2014-03-18 23:59:23,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing data-local task task_201403170135_0018_m_000000
2014-03-18 23:59:23,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Removing task 'attempt_201403170135_0018_m_000000_1'
```

PS: I actually tried running 2 programs: wordcount as well as the above one just to check my first program was correct or not. But for both I can't go further. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Got the issue. I didn't declare the classes static that messed up the whole thing. Though my code above is not full, I still have to complete the reducer, but I got the issue now.

Comment: Just an FYI: MapR in the Hadoop world is actually a company and a competitor to Cloudera.  So... probably stick with the term 'MapReduce' instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update climbage. Yes, I'm aware of MapR company, probably I'll change my mode of expression of MapReduce!